# Basic json_to_recordset Query Getting 'set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set'

Tags: postgresql

I am doing a basic `json_to_recordset` query that, as far as I can tell, follows the pattern in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html). But I am getting an error that I don't understand. (I'll summarize my research after the code sample.)

```
select my_schema.my_func(2, 2366800)
=>    my_func
      json
      ----------------------------------------------------
      [{"col_a":"...", "col_b":"...", "col_c":"..."}, ...]

select *
from json_to_recordset(my_schema.my_func(2, 2366800))
as results (col_a         TEXT,
            col_b         TEXT,
            col_c         NUMERIC(10,2))
=> ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

In addition to the docs, I have patterned my query on other examples of `json_to_recordset`. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445088/1780295), [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98195), [3](https://www.postgres-xl.org/documentation/functions-json.html)) As far as I can tell, my query should work.

I have looked into the `set-valued function` error. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112493/set-valued-function-called-in-context-that-cannot-accept-a-set), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826990/postgresql-coalesce-and-set-valued-function-called-in-context-that-cannot-accept), [3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37571/error-set-valued-function-called-in-context-that-cannot-accept-a-set-what-is-i); even [4](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/49B18742.5030408%40iol.ie), which says, "When a function returns SETOF something, you need to treat it as if it were a table.") Unfortunately, I have found no explanation of why this error is occurring this particular query.

Comment: Everything indicates that the function is incorrectly defined. If it returns `setof json` change it to `json`. Or edit the question and show the function.

Comment: @klin Spot on: The function's return type is `setof json`. I haven't used functions much, so I will need to figure out how to modify the function appropriately -- or how to convert the `setof json` to `json`. (The function starts with `RETURN QUERY select array_to_json(...) ...`, so I'll need to learn how to rewrite that without `QUERY`.) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My other answer is the immediate answer to my question, but I want to list the solution separately because the solution is rather specific to this situation, while the answer is general.

The simplest solution would be to modify `my_func` to return `json` instead of `setof json` but this function is used elsewhere, so I wanted to handle the type mismatch without modifying `my_func`.

As noted [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/49B18742.5030408%40iol.ie), "When a function returns SETOF something, you need to treat it as if it were a table." So the solution involves treating the output of `my_func` as a table (of a single value), and passing that one row to the `json_to_recordset` function. Postgres's lateral join did the trick:

```
select results.*
from my_spec.my_func(2, 2366800) json,
     lateral json_to_recordset(json)
          as results (col_a         TEXT,
                      col_b         TEXT,
                      col_c         NUMERIC(10,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

As identified in the comment by @klin, the problem was that `my_func` was returning `setof json` and `json_to_recordset` takes `json`. That type mismatch is what caused the error.